Docker login to AWS ECR throwing no basic auth error on aws ec2 instance?
I am trying to pull some private docker images which have been pushed to aws ECR private registry.
I have created a CI CD pipeline on github actions to automate the building of images and pushing them to aws ECR. This happens on a Ubuntu runner hosted by github.
Then, on my aws ec2 instance I have to pull these images from ECR. Prior to doing this, I login to AWS ECR by the preferred method i.e
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login -u AWS --password-stdin "https://$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query 'Account' --output text).dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" 


Depsite this I get the error,
No basic auth credentials
To debug the issue, I sshed into the server and verified that the aws cli has been set correctly as well. So my aws cli was authorized as well.
Why else would there be a problem in pulling images from ECR private registry?
Is it something related to ECR private registry permissions?
If this were the case then pushing would also have failed?

I would try manually running each aws command separately: aws sts get-caller-identity --query 'Account' --output text and aws ecr get-login-password on the EC2 instance, and make sure those return valid values, not errors. I would also makes sure you aren't running your docker commands with sudo since you aren't using sudo for the docker login command.

The issue was that I was not logging into aws ecr as sudo but was trying to pull the docker image as sudo so there was a conflict there.
So the solution for me was to run sudo login ... and afterwards sudo docker pull {ecr docker image}.

Saved my day, thanks!
